# Копирование данных через linked server MS SQL

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, integration-services

Существует внутреняя корпоративная сеть и внешний сервер. Находятся в разных доменах.

Осуществляю копиование данных между БД путём SSIS package.В пакете различные SQL tasks на вставку данных.

Какие существуют методы переноса информации, поскольку такой подход занимает длительное время?(Insert 14 500 тыс строк занимает >20 минут)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Экспорт - импорт, прямые insert или merge через linked, последнее можно настроить как job.

Comment: merge не работает, поскольку из корпоративной сети я вижу сервер, а внешний сервер не видит внутренний, из-за политики безопасности комании.
Сейчас и работает путем прямых insert.

Comment: время можно сэкономить, если переносить только изменения + Надо понять где узкое место такого метода - запрос долго на удаленном сервере выполняется или по сети данные долго идут. от этого уже будет зависеть стратегия оптимизации